# Is it possible to create element on the fly with jQuery Mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an app built using jQuery (and using various jQuery-UI tools).

For some reason, i have to port it to smartphones/tablet computer, and decided to use jQuery Mobile for that (in order to minimize the number of changes).

In my vanilla app, I created some elements of the page on the fly, depending of user interactions.

For example a slider could be created like that (p is an object with a bunch of params):

```
function createSlider(p){
     return $("<div/>",{
              "id":p.id,
              "class":p.divClass,
           }).slider({
              "orientation": p.align,
              "min":p.constraint.min,
              "max":p.constraint.max,
              "step":p.step,
              "value":p.curVal,
              "animate":"normal"
              /*and some event handling here, but it doesn't matter*/
           });

}
```

And it will produce a nice looking slider. Now it looks like:

```
function createSlider(p){
    return $("<range/>",{
           "id":p.id,
           "class":p.divClass,
           "min":p.constraint.min,
           "max":p.constraint.max,
           "step":p.step,
           "value":p.curVal,
    });   
}
```

But as it's created on the fly, all the stuff done by jQuery Mobile on the page load isn't done on it.

Is there a way to force that initialization without writing the slider in the html?

Thanks.

**EDIT**: I found in the [doc](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html) that it could be achieved using `container.trigger("create");`
However this does not work yet.

**EDIT2**: Ok create was the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation (see edit in the question), using `trigger("create")` on the containing element works.

And to make that work, you also need to remember that range is an input type and not a tag...

Working solution:

```
function createSlider(){
    return $("<input/>",{
           "type":"range",
           "id":"sl",
           "min":0,
           "max":15,
           "step":1,
           "value":1,
    });   
}

function appendSlider(){
    $("#yourdiv").append(createSlider()).trigger("create");
}
```

As a sidenote, the documentation for jQuery mobile lacks a search option.

Comment: This does not work for me. If I use the .trigger("create"), the dropdowns (<select...>) looks weird and behaves unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `.page()` on the container the content is being added to. Alternatively, adding `.page()` to the content you're returning may also work.

Comment: That didn't work. I also tried trigger("create"); without any success.