# JQuery mobile -> .append() removes CSS?

Tags: jquery, css, xml, append

when appending items to my list, the complete style of jquery mobile is gone... dont know how to fix this?

This is currently working: when not appending the list-items, all styles are fine.

```
<div class="ui-grid-a">
                <div class="ui-block-a" id="blockaid">
                    <ul id="leftnav" data-role="listview" data-theme="g" data-filter="true" >

                        <li><a href="index.html">
                                <img src="images/bb.jpg" />
                                <h3>Firstname Lastname</h3>
                                <p>123456789</p>
                            </a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>

               <div class="ui-block-b">
                ...
```

But if I start using to read the data from else where, all styles are gone:

```
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'test.xml', 
                dataType: "xml",
                success : parse,
                error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){  
                    alert(xhr.status);          
                    alert(thrownError);
                } 


            });

            function parse(document){
                $(document).find("Details").each(function(){


                    $("#leftnav").append(


                    '<li>' + '<a href="#">' + '<img src="images/album-xx.jpg" />' +
                        '<h3>' + $(this).find('Name').text() + '</h3>' +
                        '<p>' + $(this).find('Number').text() + '</p>' +
                        '</a>' + '</li>'
                );
                });
            }
        });
```

Whats wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I am not sure this can be a problem, but I would never use `document` as an incoming parameter name for a javascript function.

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "all styles are gone"? Is the formatting of the whole page gone? Or just on the new elements?

Comment: btw, did you try the same in 'usual' browser? I mean, chrome, firefox etc. on PC, not mobile device.

Comment: @Michael, how to write the function without document?

Comment: all styles of the new elements are gone, they are 'unformatted' // Yes i tried different browsers.

Comment: You can always give the name you want to an input variable. It's  local.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, to trigger the automatic style on new elements, using `.trigger("create")` should do the job.

see : [Is it possible to create element on the fly with jQuery Mobile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6957910/is-it-possible-to-create-element-on-the-fly-with-jquery-mobile)

or http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/pages/page-scripting.html

EDIT: `$('#leftnav').listview('refresh')` is the thing your looking for rather than create.

see: http://api.jquerymobile.com/listview/#method-refresh

Comment: Are there any more Links/Docs/Help-Files on the create function, I dont get the point yet, resfresh seems to be clear... thanks!

Comment: No the create function is only documented here from what I read.
The whole point of the create function is to initialize a whole new raw markup (let say for example if you create a new listview during the execution of your code, then you'll call create to format it).

Comment: would accept if I would get the point ... I think its a general problem for me how to structure functions..

Comment: I don't get your last comment (what do you mean by "how to structure functions"?).

Comment: currently Iam building the append() like this: $("#leftnav").append('<li class="ui-btn ui-btn-icon-right ui-li ui-li-has-thumb ui-btn-up-g" data-theme="g">' + '<div class="ui-btn-inner ui-li">' + ... and so on ... but I think this is wrong, and i don't know how to build it correctly (correctly means: without explicitly defining ui-btn-icon etc..)

Comment: That's the whole point of the refresh method, you don't have to do that. You just let your current append function as it's in the code from the question. And after the each, you add the $("#leftnav").listview("refresh"); (see http://jsfiddle.net/tKcSa/ for a little example)

Comment: This does not work for me. I dont really understand it. If its not a listview, then what? I use append a lot, and then most of the CSS is destroyed somehow. In this case I have a data-role="button", but if I run $("#t1").append(html).button('refresh')  (t1=my div), I just get an "cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"