# Lost of JQuery Mobile CSS Style after append() listview Javascript

Tags: javascript, listview, append, refresh, jquery-mobile

I know this question has been asked before, but I've tried all the solutions I could find, but to no avail.

My jqm styles does not get initialized, very much like this guy's problem: [JQuery mobile -> .append() removes CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7226998/jquery-mobile-append-removes-css)
I've tried both the .trigger('create') and listview('refresh') method, and even a combination of both.

Jade:

```
    #category(data-role='page')
      a(href='#automobile', data-transition='slide', onclick="return loadItemsBrief('automobile');")
          | Automobile
    ... //code reduced here
    #automobile(data-role='page')
     div(data-role='content')
       div#refresh(data-role='fieldcontain')
         ul#autoList(data-role='listview', data-divider-theme='b', data-inset='true')
```

Javascript (separate .js)

```
    function loadItemsBrief(cat){ 
     $.getJSON(''+cat, function (json) {
      $.each(json.items,function(i,data) {
       $('#autoList').append('<li data-theme="c"><a href="" data-transition="slide" class="touchableButton"><div style="display: inline-block"><img style="width: 100px; height: 125px" src=""'+data.fileUrls[0]+'></div><div style="display: inline-block"><h3>Title: '+data.name+'</h3><h3>Price: '+data.minBid+'</h3><h3>Condition: '+data.condition+'</h3></div></a></li>'); //tried .trigger('create') here
      });
      $('#autoList').listview('refresh'); //also tried placing .listview('refresh') in inner most layer
     });
    }
```

The error firebug gives me is:

```
TypeError: $(...).listview is not a function
$("#autoList").listview("refresh");
```

Help will be much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, after trying all the possible solutions, I tried changing my JQuery Version to 1.8.3 and leaving my JQM version at 1.3.1 works for me. Now all the listviews refresh as per normal.